# Как получить имя динамической библиотеки из boost через cmake?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, boost, cmake

Столкнулся с такой проблемой под `windows vs`: когда создаю цель для установки через `cmake`

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:Boost::log>)
```

То в папке, в которую была произведена установка, обнаруживаю статическую библиотеку, а мне нужна динамическая. Вопрос: как ее получить при обращении через `Boost::`? Можно, конечно прямо писать имя `dll`, но это чревато множеством проблем (кроссплатформенность, разные версии), так что это не вариант.

Comment: Не знаю как с INSTALL, но с линковкой работает отлично...  target_link_libraries(project ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) При условии что должна быть выставлена системная переменная BOOST_ROOT

Comment: Подробнее здесь: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: @VladimirBalun вопрос конкретно про install, а не про линковку - с этим как раз таки пробем нет

Comment: Я отметил, что "Не знаю как с INSTALL, но с линковкой работает отлично.."